# History of normal operator (matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, education, math-history

I need help please, i'm looking for a little history of the normality of the linear operators (like matrices), the creator.....ect and why we need  linear operator to be normal (example of real life). I already search but I did not find

Thank you a lot !

Comment: One of the main "creators" is Hermann Weyl, who, besides had a clear writing (mainly in the 1920s). Rapid progresses where done in connection with the nascent quantum mechanics at that time.

Comment: You can search for normal matrices equivalent definitions, they are many.